# Update Datepickerfield from Model Sencha Touch

Tags: forms, model, datepicker, sencha-touch, store

I have a model and store that take in values from my form fields. 
My form contains a textfield, selectfield, datepickerfield and radiofield.

I take the values from the form and update my model with them. When later I load the model into the form, the values reappear on all components EXCEPT the datepickerfield.

Im using a localstorage proxy. I checked the values in the database, the date shows in the following format : "2011-12-13T18:30:00.000Z"

I think this may be the problem. Maybe the datepickerfield doesnt know how to load the format. What should I do ??

Sasha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're telling me is the ways to format the date, not how to do it… 
But the date still doesnt load & the format is wrong. 
No actually I found the answer, this is what you have to do :

1. Your showForm controller (to load the date in the form)should look something like this : 
   showForm : function (params) {

   ```
   //load the model necessary
   var model = BReimb.stores.ListStore.getAt(params.index);

   //load all fields except datepickerfield
   Ext.getCmp('formPane').load(model);
   Ext.getCmp('MainView').setActiveItem(1);

   //for datepicker field --> where the Ext.getCmp('date') is the id of my datepicker field in the form

   if(model.data.date != "")
       Ext.getCmp('date').setValue(new Date(model.data.date));
   ```
2. To format the date, incase ur using an itemTpl it shud be : 
   itemTpl : '{date:date("d M Y")}'

Hope this helps someone :D

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that date formats to other using the code below .
Initially set the date patterns , ie

```
Date.patterns = {
    ISO8601Long : "Y-m-d H:i:s",
    ISO8601Short : "Y-m-d",
    ShortDate : "n/j/Y",
    LongDate : "l, F d, Y",
    FullDateTime : "l, F d, Y g:i:s A",
    MonthDay : "F d",
    ShortTime : "g:i A",
    LongTime : "g:i:s A",
    SortableDateTime : "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s",
    UniversalSortableDateTime : "Y-m-d H:i:sO",
    YearMonth : "F, Y"
};
```

Then apply this date patterns as follows , ie

```
yourDate.format(Date.patterns.ISO8601Short);
yourDate.format(Date.patterns.FullDateTime);
```

Hope it will help...